# How can I prevent a mat-expansion-panel from opening when clicked?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to control my mat-expansion-panel **solely with the panel's [expanded] input property**. I am using NGRX as state management.

Therefore, I **don't want the panel to open when clicked**. Instead, I have my own click listener that will dispatch the right action that will lead to the panel to open.

How can I prevent it from opening when clicked? I tried **(click)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();** but it does not do the trick.

```
<mat-accordion [multi]="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="item.isOpen">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="togglePanel($event, item)">
        <!-- Header Content-->
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <!-- Panel Content -->
    </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not (from what I know) built in way to disable the click of the panels, thought there's a simple trick using only CSS to accomplish what you want.

You can set the style to `pointer-events: none;` to the `<mat-expansion-panel>` and it won't listen to any click events, and then you toggle it your way using your custom logic.

I made a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gb4ryn) to demonstrate it.